# Using data from pythons pandas dataframes to sample from normal distributions

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sample from a normal distribution using means and standard deviations that are stored in pandas DataFrames.

For example:

```
means= numpy.arange(10)
means=means.reshape(5,2)
```

produces:

```
   0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```

and:

```
sts=numpy.arange(10,20)
sts=sts.reshape(5,2)
```

produces:

```
    0   1
0  10  11
1  12  13
2  14  15
3  16  17
4  18  19
```

How would I produce another pandas dataframe with the same shape but with values sampled from the normal distribution using the corresponding means and standard deviations.

i.e. position `0,0` of this new dataframe would sample from a normal distribution with `mean=0` and `standard deviation=10`, and so on.

My function so far:

```
    def make_distributions(self):
        num_data_points,num_species= self.means.shape
        samples=[]
        for i,j in zip(self.means,self.stds):
            for k,l in  zip(self.means[i],self.stds[j]):
                samples.append( numpy.random.normal(k,l,self.n) )
```

will sample from the distributions for me but I'm having difficulty putting the data back into the same shaped dataframe as the mean and standard deviation dfs. Does anybody have any suggestions as to how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.random.normal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) to sample from a random normal distribution.
IIUC, then this might be easiest, taking advantage of [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1) # only for demonstration
np.random.normal(means,sts)

array([[ 16.24345364,  -5.72932055],
       [ -4.33806103, -10.94859209],
       [ 16.11570681, -29.52308045],
       [ 33.91698823,  -5.94051732],
       [ 13.74270373,   4.26196287]])
```

Check that it works:

```
np.random.seed(1)
print np.random.normal(0,10)
print np.random.normal(1,11)

16.2434536366
-5.72932055015
```

If you need a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(means,sts))
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, This looks great  but can I just check that i understand... What you are saying is that the command `np.random.normal(means,sts)` will take two df's (mean and sts) and sample from the normal distribution on an element by element basis? So essentially it works the exact same way as it would if means and sts were integers/floats? cheers

Comment: I think you understand it correctly.  If you check out the broadcasting link, it shows you some really trivial examples, like array `a` * array `b`, so that you can visualize the operation.  That's why I included the print statements, in the second block, to replicate the behavior with ints.  I think you've got it though!  Broadcasting is a very powerful built-in numpy tool that can provide dramatic performance upgrades and avoid for loops on large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

I will use dictionary to construct this dataframe. Suppose indices and columns are the same for means and stds:

```
means= numpy.arange(10)
means=pd.DataFrame(means.reshape(5,2))
stds=numpy.arange(10,20)
stds=pd.DataFrame(sts.reshape(5,2))

samples={}
for i in means.columns:
    col={}
    for j in means.index:
        col[j]=numpy.random.normal(means.ix[j,i],stds.ix[j,i],2)
    samples[i]=col

print(pd.DataFrame(samples))

#                                  0                                1
#0  [0.0760974520154, 3.29439282825]  [11.1292510583, 0.318246201796]
#1   [-25.4518020981, 19.2176263823]   [17.0826945017, 9.36179435872]
#2    [14.5402484325, 8.33808246538]   [6.96459947914, 26.5552235093]
#3  [0.775891790613, -2.09168601369]   [2.38723023677, 15.8099942902]
#4  [-0.828518484847, 45.4592922652]   [26.8088977308, 16.0818556353]
```

Or reset the dtype of a DataFrame and reassign values:

```
import itertools
samples = means * 0
samples = samples.astype(object)

for i,j in itertools.product(means.index, means.columns):
    samples.set_value(i,j,numpy.random.normal(means.ix[i,j],stds.ix[i,j],2))
```